# Unwanted <p> paragraphs spawned in civiMail body forms

Tags: civimail

Whenever I save a draft email in civiMail, one or more

tags are added to the top. I have to remove them each time. If I don't, even more are added with each save. Does anyone know what's happening?

civiCRM 4.6.13

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this happening as well. Possibly, but not definitely, related and worth exploring: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30984/ckeditor-adds-extra-p-tags